Select component isn't displayed correctly
I want to use Shadcn/vue for my website and I followed (hopefully correctly) the instructions here to set up the project.
Now I installed the Button and the Select-component with the commands npx shadcn-vue@latest add button and npx shadcn-vue@latest add select respectively.
I have create a small test component UseSelectTest.vue the code of which is here:
//UseSelectTest.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectGroup,
  SelectItem,
  SelectLabel,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from '@/components/ui/select';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
</script>

<template>
  <Select>
    <SelectTrigger>
      <SelectValue placeholder="Select a fruit" />
    </SelectTrigger>
    <SelectContent>
      <SelectGroup>
        <SelectLabel>Fruits</SelectLabel>
        <SelectItem value="apple">
          Apple
        </SelectItem>
      </SelectGroup>
    </SelectContent>
  </Select>

  <Button>This button is nice</Button>
</template>

If I include this component somewhere in the webpage, the button looks very nice and as expected, but the Select component is just empty!
The error message I get is:
vue-mc-gaps.vue:1 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: SelectValue
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 

If I include
plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag : string) => ['Select', 'FormControl', 'SelectTrigger', 'SelectContent', 'SelectGroup', 'SelectItem','SelectLabel','SelectTrigger','SelectValue'].includes(tag), //
        }
      }
    })
  ]

in vite.config.ts,
that error message disappears but still the Select component isn't displayed correctly.
My configuration files look like:
//vie.config.ts


import path from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwind(), autoprefixer()],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag : string) => ['Select', 'FormControl', 'SelectTrigger', 'SelectContent', 'SelectGroup', 'SelectItem','SelectLabel','SelectTrigger','SelectValue'].includes(tag), //
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
});

and another configuration file
//tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

When I run npm run build or npm run dev, it gives me no error messages.
What do I do wrong?

Have you checked for the existence of the component at the import path?  It should be added to your project in @/components/ui/select. First thing to do is verify it exists, and you may need to try reinstalling.
